# "Error in prettyNum" in ...rpy2\robject\functions.py

Tags: r, rpy2

I am getting an error from my input object which goes through ...\rpy2\robjects\functions.py. Specifically:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Kaggle\UPenn_and_Mayo_Clinic_Seizure_Detection\Scripts\py_test01.py", line 174, in <module>
featureEEG = R_EEGA.FeatureEEG(data = time_series_object, classes_Id = classes_id_matrix, rec_Id = record_id_matrix)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 90, in __call__
return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 39, in __call__
res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I am guessing the function does not like the object sent to it. FYI, be wary of the line numbers above, a few **print()** statements were placed into ...\function.py to track where the offended line is located (therefore they do not correspond with line numbers in unaltered ...\function.py). The lines of **...\function.py** code having problems with the input are in the **__call__** function of a **Function** class object:

```
res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
res = conversion.ri2py(res)  ### this is the error line ###
```

where,

new_args = [ ]

new_kwargs =

```
 {'rec.Id': <Matrix - Python:0x0647C698 / R:0x08734740> [       1,        1,        1, ...,        4,        4,        4], 
'classes.Id': <Matrix - Python:0x0651B4B8 / R:0x08A0F1E8> [       1,        1,        1, ...,        2,        2,        2], 
'data': <Matrix Python:0x065228A0 / R:0x0D740008> [-42.880000, -48.880000, -70.880000, ..., -6.105000, -4.105000, -10.105000]}
```

The above matrices are inputs from this line of code:

```
featureEEG = R_EEGA.FeatureEEG(data = time_series_object, classes_Id = classes_id_matrix, rec_Id = record_id_matrix)
```

where R_EEGA is the R eegAnalysis package

Any idea how to make this run correctly? Any additional code needed to understand the situation? Any suggestions where I can find the answer?

Thank You

Comment: If you could give a fully reproducible example that would always be useful, though it may not be 100% necessary

Comment: @NerdLife2, When people ask for a "fully reproducible" example, to what degree are they asking? I could create a condensed version but start wondering if it then will create the same problem or not. Also, how to handle pulling data from a database?

Answer (score 0):

`trim` needs a true `TRUE` or `FALSE` argument. The fact that `new_args` = [] instead of a valid argument may well be the cause of the problem.

The same error occurred in a different context in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/interpreting-date-related-error-message-td2341543.html).

Answer (score 0):

@NerdLife provided help with getting around the error:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

a solution for this situation was to add 'trim' as an argument as follows:

```
    featureEEG = R_EEGA.FeatureEEG(data = time_series_object,
                                   classes_Id = classes_id_matrix,
                                   rec_Id = record_id_matrix,
                                   trim = R_base.logical(1 == 1)) ### added this last portion ###
```

Now, when the code is run -- either with 'trim' = TRUE or 'trim' = FALSE -- the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Projects\Kaggle\UPenn_and_Mayo_Clinic_Seizure_Detection\Scripts\py_test01.py", 
line 177, in <module> trim = R_base.logical(1 == 1)) 
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", 
line 86, in __call__ return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", 
line 35, in __call__ res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs) 
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (length = 0L)  : invalid 'length' argument
```

Since this is new error I'll create a new question for it, and will post a link to it here soon.

Thank You *NerdLife* for helping me get past the 'trim' error!

Here is the link if anyone wants to follow the next part of this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972783/rpy2-rinterface-rruntimeerror-error-in-function-length-0l-invalid-lengt